# Rules Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was wondering if it’s possible to cross collections to set a rule.
Maybe by mixing `exists()` and `get()` ?

My `Collection` is like that :

```
- BusinessOwners
      |
      |_ autoID ___ businessID: String
                 |_ userID: String
      |
      |_ autoID ___ businessID: String
                 |_ userID: String
```

I would like to check (with my words) if:

1. **Exists** a `Document` in `BusinessOwners`
2. With `userID == request.auth.uid` **&&** `businessID == IDspecified`

My match part would be like:

```
function isOwnerOfTheBusiness(IDspecified){
    return ???;
}

match /userresults/{docID} {
        allow write, read: if isOwnerOfTheBusiness(request.resource.data.businessID);
}
```

Can I do that? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible exactly as you describe, because you can't perform queries in security rules.  The only way you can access documents other than the one being accessed is if you know the full path, including the document ID.  If you know the path, you can use `get()` and `exists()` with that path.  But you just can't query a collection with conditions.

Comment: perfectly right. Just tried it myself but wildcards are not allowed in get() function. I really couldnt believe it first so i tripple checked. I think such a rule would be too time consuming. Looks like he needs to do some refactoring if he really wants to solve it on security-rule level.